# How to replace '?' from ?word1 word2? with Regex

Tags: c#, regex

We are importing some text from a bad export someone made and it's full of question mark characters where double quotes used to be.

Is there a regex replace I can do to replace `?` with `"`? Examples:

```
?foo? => "foo"
?foo bar? => "foo bar"
foo? => foo?
```

Comment: Yes, there is one. What have you tried?

Comment: Are you sure it's question mark characters (`\u0063`) and not just some invalid encoding?

Comment: Hm, @Bergi, you're right - the question marks do come from invalid encoding but they have been lost somewhere in the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the regex `\?(.*)\?` to match something between `?` marks.

But if you do it like that, in the example `a ?b? ?c? d` it would result in `a "b? ?c" d` because it matches the longest substring `?b? ?c?`.

To solve this, you need to use lazy-matching with the regex `\?(.*?)\?`, which would result in `a "b" "c" d`.

If there can't be two question marks together as in `a ?? b`, then it should be `\?(.+?)\?`. So:

```
Regex.Replace(text, @"\?(.+?)\?", "\"$1\"");
```

The `$1` means "whatever was recognized in the first group", that is, whatever was recognized by `.+?`.

**Edit:** A faster alternative is:

```
Regex.Replace(text, @"\?([^\?]+)\?", "\"$1\"");
```

`[^\?]` means "anything but `\?`".

Comment: Could you provide a C# replace method? This doesn't seem to work: Regex.Replace("?foo bar?", @"\?(.+?)\?", "\"") (and no, there can't be two ??)

Comment: Added at the end of the answer

Comment: Thank you, accepting as answer since it's the first one to provide a C# replace example as asked.

Comment: Why lazy-matching?! Won't \?[^?]+\? do? It's much faster and leads to less errors since it cannot be interpreted incorrectly!

Comment: Yeah, `\?([^\?]+)\?` would be faster

Comment: Actually no need for the `\?` inside the `[]`, `[]` should escape automatically.

Comment: It wouldn't only be faster, but it's even correcter. In your expression it doesn't really really matter, but as this expression might get extended over time, `.+?` might cause the expression to include a `?` in the match when it needs to find one, where `[^?]+` will never silently include a `?` in the match.

Answer (score 1):

The regex

```
/\?\b(.+?)\b\?/g
```

should do it - match all question marks (which [need to be escaped](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html)) that come next to [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html), and do it [non-greedy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy).

Comment: Still doesn't work - Regex.Replace("?foo?", @"/\?\b(.+?)\b\?/", "\"$1\"") => foo. See accepted answer for correct C# impl.

Comment: OK, forget my non-existing C#-knowledge :-)

Comment: Apparently everybody used Perl/sed-like syntax :-)

Comment: …and I copied the syntax from them. Evil me :-/

Comment: Because it uses a non-greedy match where a possessive match of `\?[^?]+\?` would work, which is safer, faster and more precise.

Comment: @jessehouwing: OK, as said I don't know C# :-/. And why would `[^?]+` be better than `.+?`? OK, in a dumb regex implementation if might be little faster if the aim was just to match until the next `?`, but it wouldn't work with my word boundary then (which is there on purpose).

Comment: It is bad because people learn to use lazy evaluation for everything. Especially when you combine lazy evaluation like this `ab*?ab*?ab?a` and it turns out that there is no 4th a in a long text can result in a very slow execution with very high amounts of backtracking. When combined with `.+?` or `[a-z]+?` it gets worse, since the engine will ignore one of these characters when it needs to backtrack, leading to unexpected results for novice users. `[^?]+` can only be interpreted in one way by the engine, plus it normally performs better. Don't teach lazy, unless you really need it.

Comment: Say `bla???????bla` will, with your regex, match `???????`, since your word boundaries don't make much sense. With `\?[^?]*\?` it will match `??, ??, ??`, three empty pairs of question marks. With `\?[^?]+\?` it wouldn't match anything, which is probably the desired behavior. Be really careful combining lazy matching with `.*` or `.+`, and always look for a solution that is greedy, unless you have no alternative. Often a possessive `(?>[^?]+)` is even faster and can lead to even fewer errors, but is harder to understand. A possessive regex does not ever backtrack. In Java that would be `++`.

Comment: OK, for educational purpose it might be better, but you had to downvote nearly every [tag:regex] answer then :-) And no, mine won't match `bla???bla` since the word boundaries are on the inside. It would match `bla ?word ? word? bla` different from yours, and `bla??? bla` not at all for example.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex should be `/^\?([^?]+)\?$/`

Comment: How would it work with replace? This doesn't work: Regex.Replace("?foo bar?", @"/^\?([^?]+)\?$/", "\"")

Comment: `Regex.Replace(value, @"/^\?([^?]+)\?$/", "\"$1\"");`

Comment: Ok... details? What is the problem?

Comment: Regex.Replace("?foo bar?", @"/^\?([^?]+)\?$/", "\"$1\"") => ?foo bar?

Comment: Why the anchors? I think OP has them somewhere in lots of plain text

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
s/\?(.*)\?/$1
```

It grab the chars in between "?"

Comment: This would match the longest substring, so `a ?b? ?c? d` wouldn't work. He needs to use lazy-matching.

Comment: It would not match the longest, but the first on every line (depending on the state of RegexOptions.SingleLine. The syntax used here doesn't work in C# either, it's in perl/javascript syntax.